# How to monitor connection issues of Neo4j?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, neo4j, bolt

I use Neo4j Community Edition. To create a backup I have to stop the Neo4j process, make a backup and start the process again. I want to create a watcher for the connection to the database on the server side to I'll be able to show to users some alert message that the DB is not available.

I use the driver [neo4j-javascript-driver](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-javascript-driver).

Similar to other drivers for databases I assumed that Neo4j has something similar to:

```
const driver = neo4j.driver('bolt://localhost', neo4j.auth.basic('neo4j', 'neo4j'));
const session = driver.session();

session.on('disconnect', () => console.log('disconnected'));
```

But the docs doesn't contain anything about this. If Neo4j doesn't have something similar, than I would like to connect to the bolt port using a custom [socket.io](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io) connection, for instance:

```
const ioc = require('socket.io-client');

const NEO4J_BOLT_URL = 'https://localhost:7687';

const client = ioc.connect(NEO4J_BOLT_URL, {
  path: '/',
  transports: ['websocket'],
});

client.on('connect', () => console.log('connected'));
client.on('disconnect', () => console.log('disconnected'));

client.on('reconnect', () => console.log('reconnected'));
client.on('reconnect_error', (err) => console.log('attempt to reconnect has failed', err));
```

(it doesn't work)

Could someone help me to implement something similar into this driver? The main thing what I need are callbacks when the Neo4j database alive or not.

Comment: I think it definitely needs such a feature. I'm planning to run a very simple query to check DB connectivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neo4j's driver maintains a pool of connections to the database.

When you ask the driver for a new session, the driver will take a connection form the pool (or create one if needed).

There is no `connect` or `disconnect` events.

The only thing you can do it's to catch the error when you perform a transaction and check if the type of the error is `SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE` (https://neo4j.com/docs/api/javascript-driver/current/variable/index.html#static-variable-SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE).